# Transpose datafra with date columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that has one column with a City and the next columns are values of power consumption by datetime, each datetime is the header of the column, the header is like that:

City | 01/01/2022 00:00 |  01/01/2022 01:00 | 01/01/2022 02:00 | 01/01/2022 03:00 |.......

If I do df.T it works well but the datetimes are now the index of the Dataframe and all of this values in the index column have the string "date." at the beginning of the vale like this: data.01/01/2022 00:00, data.01/01/2022 01:00, data.01/01/2022 02:00... and I dont know why.

My purpose is to get the dataframe with the values organized by datetime in rows and the cities in columns

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a more explicit format for your input/output data

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't super clear but I think this is what you want?

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "City": ["New York", "Chicago", "Tokyo", "Paris"],
    "01/01/2022 00:00": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "01/01/2022 01:00": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    "01/01/2022 02:00 ": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.transpose().reset_index()
df = (
    df
    .rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
    .drop(df.index[0])
    .rename(columns={"City": "Date"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
print(df)

                 Date New York Chicago Tokyo Paris
0 2022-01-01 00:00:00        1       2     3     4
1 2022-01-01 01:00:00        5       6     7     8
2 2022-01-01 02:00:00        A       B     C     D
```